# jQuery image display issue

Tags: jquery

I have a div structure like following:

```
<div id="image0" style="margin-bottom:10px; "></div>
<div id="image1" style="margin-bottom:10px; "></div>
<div id="image2" style="margin-bottom:10px; "></div>
<div id="image3" style="margin-bottom:10px; "></div>
<div id="image4" style="margin-bottom:10px; "></div>
```

My jQuery code is like follows:

```
var res = question.text.split(imgQues);
    if (question.image != '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < res[0]; i++) {
            jQuery('#image' + "" + i).html(question.image);
        }
    } else {
        jQuery('#image' + "" + i).html('');
    }
```

In my case if the res[0] is "5" code will loop to display 5 image  and if res[0] value is  "1" then its 1 image.

With my above code, it displays 5 images at the beginning but for next time it is still displaying 5 image not 1.

Comment: Try clear `#image##` every time.

Comment: possibly your `else` will have undefined `i` variable

Comment: It is an undefined Question, think how you can excess a loop variable outside the scope ... watch out for errors in console

Comment: Yes. i forgot to remove i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it, you are replacing the content of the `div`s each time.
So when `res[0]` is smaller than the total number of `div`s, the `div`s with larger IDs would be left untouched.

To solve this problem, you first have to define the total number of these image `div`s, say in your example, there are at most 5 of them.

so: `var max = 5;`

Now change your code a bit so we clear those larger IDs :

```
var max = 5;
var res = question.text.split(imgQues);
var i;
// Clear them out first
for (i = 0; i < max; i++){
    jQuery('#image' + "" + i).html('');
}
if (question.image != '') {
    for (i = 0; i < res[0]; i++) {
        jQuery('#image' + "" + i).html(question.image);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it might be more desirable to do it this way, so there isn't a need to keep track of how many image `div`s there are:

HTML:

```
<div id="image-container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-image {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var imgContainer = jQuery("#image-container");
imgContainer.html(""); // Clear contents
if (question.image != '') {
    var res = question.text.split(imgQues);
    for(var i = 0; i < res[0]; i++){
        var newImage = jQuery("<div class=\"my-image\"></div>");
        newImage.html(question.image);
        imgContainer.append(newImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for idea

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (var j = 0; j < res; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < res[j]; i++) {
            $('#image' + "" + i).html(question.image);
        }
    }
```

You have to add two loops like this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I forgot to clear div. Its working now. Thank you.